# Use Zurb Foundation without breaking existing code

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Foundation is good for creating the whole page design but not a good choice when it comes to small snippet that you want to include inside existing code (html, css). 
Foundation have this in the `_global.scss`:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

// Set box-sizing globally to handle padding and border widths
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  @include box-sizing(inherit);
}
```

This destroys existing designs.

My question is; how can i integrate the Foundation based snippet div inside a page, profiting of what Foundation has to offer (rows, columns..) without breaing the other code. Without using iFrames.

Comment: If your old designs use `box-sizing: content-box` because they are older, it might be worth it to update your existing designs to adapt `border-box` as well.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean.. I didn't understand :(

Comment: These days, `border-box` is the preferred box model for a number of reasons: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/
So it probably makes sense to update your old designs to make them work with `box-sizing: border-box`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Global Styles](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/global.html) page of the [Foundation Docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs):

> ### Global Styles
>
> Every Foundation project needs to include these global styles in order to work properly. These include things like basic formatting and global utility classes.

If you want to use the grid you have to include the `_global.scss` file, so you're going to have to update the old layout to support `box-sizing: border-box` or adjust the entire layout to work with Foundation.